# Accessing elements of a placeholder in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I have a neural network with MSE loss function being implemented something like this:

```
# input x_ph is of size Nx1 and output should also be of size Nx1
def train_neural_network_batch(x_ph, predict=False):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x_ph)

    # MSE loss function
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(prediction - y_ph))

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(cost)

    # mini-batch optimization here
```

I'm fairly new to neural networks and Python, but I understand that each iteration, a sample of training points will be fed into the neural network and the loss function evaluated at the points in this sample. However, I would like to be able to modify the loss function so that it weights certain data more heavily. Some pseudocode of what I mean

```
# manually compute the MSE of the data without the first sampled element
cost = 0.0
for ii in range(1,len(y_ph)):
    cost += tf.square(prediction[ii] - y_ph[ii])

cost = cost/(len(y_ph)-1.0)

# weight the first sampled data point more heavily according to some parameter W
cost += W*(prediction[0] - y_ph[0])
```

I might have more points I wish to weight differently as well, but for now, I'm just wondering how I can implement something like this in tensorflow. I know `len(y_ph)` is invalid as `y_ph` is just a placeholder, and I can't just do something like `y_ph[i]` or `prediction[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multiple ways:

1) If some of your data instances weighting are simply 2 times or 3 times more than normal instance, you may just copy those instance multiple times in your data set. Thus they would occupy more weight in loss, hence satisfy your intention. This is the simplest way.

2) If your weighting is more complex, say a float weighting. You can define a placeholder for weighting, multiply it to loss, and use feed_dict to feed the weighting in session together with x batch and y batch. Just make sure instance_weight is the same size with batch_size

E.g.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.variable_scope("test", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
  y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
  instance_weight = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
  w1 = tf.get_variable("w1", shape=[1, 1])
  prediction = tf.matmul(x, w1)

  cost = tf.square(prediction - y)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(instance_weight * cost)
  opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  x1 = [[1.],[2.],[3.]]
  y1 = [[2.],[4.],[3.]]
  instance_weight1 = [[10.0], [10.0], [0.1]]
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print (x1)
  print (y1)
  print (instance_weight1)
  for i in range(1000):
    _, loss1, prediction1 = sess.run([opt, loss, prediction], feed_dict={instance_weight : instance_weight1, x : x1, y : y1 }) 
    if (i % 100) == 0:
      print(loss1)
      print(prediction1)
```

NOTE instance_weight1, you may change instance_weight1 to see the difference (here batch_size is set to 3)

Where x1,y1 and x2,y2 follow the rule y=2*x

Whereas x3,y3 follow the rule y=x

But with different weight as [10,10,0.1], the prediction1 coverage to y1,y2 rule and almost ignored y3, the output are as:

```
[[1.9823183]
 [3.9646366]
 [5.9469547]]
```

PS: in tensorflow graph, it's highly recommended not to use for loops, but use matrix operator instead to parallel the calculation.